# Adding Custom popup doesn't filling the full view iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, popup

I have created a UIViewControlller and designed in storyboard, I want to show it as popup for my another view. 
I used the following to show as popup:

```
 guard let popupVC = UIStoryboard(name: "More", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LanguageSelectionViewController") as? LanguageSelectionViewController else{
            fatalError("Unexpected destination VC")
        }

        self.addChildViewController(popupVC)

        popupVC.view.frame = self.tableView.frame


        print("POPUP Frame VIEW   -- \(popupVC.view.frame)")
        print("SElF VIEW   -- \(self.tableView.frame)")

        popupVC.view.frame = self.tableView.frame


        print("POPUP Frame VIEW   -- \(popupVC.view.frame)")
        print("SElF VIEW   -- \(self.view.frame)")

        popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
        popupVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        popupVC.view.bindFrameToSuperviewBounds()
        self.view.addSubview(popupVC.view)
        popupVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

It is working properly, but on my device half of the screen space is not filled by popup view.

[image: Screenshot where half screen is not filled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the present() function? Something like this:

```
let popupVC = PopupViewController()
popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
popupVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I find designing view controllers in their own xib files easier, and it allows initialisation like in my example, rather than having to use the storyboard in code, but thats personal preference.
If it still isnt working, maybe check that the layout constraints for the popup's background are correct, so it actually fills it's parent.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, but I initiated the ViewController with identifier.

Comment: The initialisation is really personal preference. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need click on popup(storyboard or xib) and set it to background color `.clear Color`

Then make it to center. like 
`popupVC.center = self.view.center`

it's just a guide you can change and set names accordingly. But my question why you are using `storyboard` why not have created `Xib or View`

Hope it will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap these two lines:

```
self.view.addSubview(popupVC.view)
popupVC.view.bindFrameToSuperviewBounds()
```

You can't bind a view to it's superview if the view hasn't been added to it yet.

Comment: doesn't worked, it is even not loading the view controller.